# Creating a Tester Class

Tags: java

I was given a basic outline for a Employee class, and have made one, I am not quite sure what is wrong with my testers though. I have made the Employee Class, and I have tried many different testers, I am not really sure why my testers are not working as it seems like it should be a basic tester class.
I want to be able to create new employees and fill out their information then return accordingly, for example Employee 1 = new Employee(24, "James", "Bob", 2500), Employee 2 = new Employee(35, "Dylan", "Brakes", 3000), then return Employee 1/ return Employee 2

```
public class Employee
{
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int salary;

    public Employee(int i, String f, String l, int s)
    {
        id=i;
        firstName=f;
        lastName=l;
        salary=s;
    }

    public int getID(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }

    public int getSalary(){
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int s){
        salary=s;
    }

    public int getAnnualSalary(){
        return salary*12;
    }

    public int raiseSalary(int p){
        salary= salary * ((p/100))+1;
        return salary;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Employee[id= " + id +" ,name= " + firstName + " " + lastName+ " ,salary= " +salary+"]";
    }
}
```

These are the various testers I have tried so far, I also have tried adding a return Employee, but that didn't change anything.

```
public class EmployeeTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

 Employee employee1 = new Employee(23, James, Dylan, 2500);

}
}
```

> I also tried this, I suspect this didn't work because I didn't use string args

```
public class EmployeeTest
{
    Employee 1 = new Employee(45, Bob, James, 3000)
}
```

> and I tried this as well.

```
public class EmployeeTest
{
    public EmployeeTest()
    {
        Employee one = new Employee(43, Bob, James, 2222);
    }        
    
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Do you get error messages? All your main method does is create an instance of an Employee, but you never actually do anything with the Employee. Maybe you just want to add `System.out.println(employee1)`. This will automatically invoke the toString() method to display the values of the Employee.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Your string literals need to be in double-quotes. `"Bob"` and `"James"`.

Comment: I want to be able to create new employees and fill out their information then return accordingly, for example Employee 1 = new Employee(24, "James", "Bob", 2500), Employee 2 = new Employee(35, "Dylan", "Brakes", 3000), then return Employee 1/ return Employee 2

Comment: What do you mean "return". You only have code in the main() method. Where to you expect to "return" the information. Your code will finish executing when the main() method is finished. I already suggested how you can "display" the data you entered when  you created the Employee.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "tester class". Maybe you mean a test, maybe not. If you mean a test - relax, try and study more Java before using external libraries and build systems. String literals (like `Bob`) should be quoted (like `"BOB"`).

Answer (score 0):

Check if this code working

```
  public class EmployeeTest {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

             Employee employee1 = new Employee(23, "James", "Dylan", 2500);
             System.out.println("printing employee1 \n"+employee1);
        }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you !! , This is exactly what I was going for but I am not sure why mine wasn't working. I was going to add the System.out.println after I get the initial Employee code working.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the keyword `this` for the fields in the constructor and setter methods

```
this.salary = salary;
```

Comment: (1-) no you do not need to use "this". Some people choose to do so to indicate the variable is an instance variable but as long a variable names are unique, there is no need to do that.

Comment: i believe the fields won't receive the data if you don't use "this" on the constructor

Comment: You would be correct if the parameter name was `salary` but it is not (`s`), so `this.` is not required.